# Click to toggle function in ngx-carousel not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, carousel, node-modules

I have integrated ngx-carousel to show some images in carousels. Everything is working as expected but the below toggle buttons are not working as expected.

I am using the ngx-carousel from [valor Software](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel)
in the website, the examples are working fine, but in my project , the toggle buttons are not working.[(buttons image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jup7.png).

can anyone suggest me any way, to make these buttons work.

```
<carousel selector="slide" [showIndicators]="true" [interval]="myInterval" [(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex" >
   <div class="col-md-12 centered">
     <div class="carousel-inner ">
         <slide  class="item animated fadeIn" *ngFor="let offer of currentOffers, let i =index" [ngClass]="{'active':i==0}">
             <blockquote>
                <ng-container >
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-sm-12 align">
                                <img width="100%" src="{{offer.imageName}}">                                                                                
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
             </blockquote>
            </slide>

     </div>
  </div>
</carousel>
```

Comment: Please consider showing us your code.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin i have added the code for carousal, that i am using. please can you check

Answer (score 0):

I got the perfect solution for this problem by the help of my senior. The thing is i had written too much of code written for the simple functionality. So i removed all code and rewrote the whole as

```
<carousel [showIndicators]="true" [interval]="myInterval" [(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex" >
   <slide class="item animated fadeIn" *ngFor="let offer of currentOffers, let i =index">
      <img [src]="offer.imageName" alt="Offer Image" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
   </slide>
</carousel>
```